# Automatically Generated UI Headers in Qt

Tags: qt

I'm working in Qt creator and am somewhat confused. When I generated a UI file in Qt Designer, I have noticed that there is an associated header file loaded in the cpp file titled ui_*filename*. I'm somewhat confused as to how this header is generated. Please refer to the picture below. The file in particular is "ui_mainwindow.h". This file is being generated automatically.

[image]

Is there any way to look at the contents of this header file

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This file is generated by the Qt [User Interface Compiler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html) which converts the XML format `*.ui` to the C++ header `ui_*.h`.

It basically contains the definition of the class `Ui::MainWindow` (the one that has the definition of the function `ui->setupUi(this)`). To view its contents in Qt creator just hold the *ctrl* key and place your mouse pointer over the file name, you will notice that it will turn into a link, click on it.

[image]