# Designing GUI programmatically - good practice for nested layouts and multiple widgets (Qt)

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qwidget, qlayout

I am interested in better understanding **Qt** and for that I would like to *see* **how a relatively complex example of nested layouts and multiples widgets GUI is done solely programmatically**; i.e. without the use of Qt Creator's Design.

I have seen several example code demonsrating only very simple layouts and -almost- always without utilising the header files; in fact most of the examples I have seen, *dump* the code in the main. It is my understanding (please correct me if I am wrong) that good programming practices dictate that you separate the design in a separate class (e.g. `mainwindow`) and in the `main.cpp` you merely invoke and `show` that main window. Perhaps, most crucially, all the definitions of widgets, layouts etc. should be defined in the header file and then invoked and customised in the `mainwindow.cpp`.

A fine exammple of good programming practices programmatically but for a  relatively simple GUI desing can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649750/6167676).

If anyone can provide *online resource(s)* where non-simple code examples of good programmatical GUI designs that show how to properly define and customise nested layouts and widgets that would be very much appreciated.

Alternatively, here is a straightforward programmatical GUI design example for which it would be great to derive code (without the Designer) for me to study and gain understanding from:

note: *my focus is only on the nested layouts, multiple widgets and the where and how these should be defined and invoked on the different Qt source files*.

[image]

where the nested layout and widget specifics can be seen here:

[image]

with the actual GUI result as seen here:

[image]

**UPDATE**

As Mike suggested in the comments section, from the [uic](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html) the code for what the Designer does can be seen, which in my case for the example mentioned above is the following

`>uic mainwindow.ui` outputs:

```
#ifndef UI_MAINWINDOW_H
#define UI_MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QFormLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QFrame>
#include <QtWidgets/QGridLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QLineEdit>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QProgressBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QSpacerItem>
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout_3;
    QFrame *top_frame;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer;
    QProgressBar *progressBar_2;
    QProgressBar *progressBar_4;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer_2;
    QPushButton *pushButton_1;
    QProgressBar *progressBar_1;
    QPushButton *pushButton_2;
    QPushButton *pushButton_3;
    QProgressBar *progressBar_3;
    QPushButton *pushButton_4;
    QFrame *bottom_frame;
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
    QFrame *frame;
    QFormLayout *formLayout;
    QLabel *label_1;
    QLabel *label_2;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer_2;
    QLineEdit *lineEdit;
    QLineEdit *lineEdit_2;
    QFrame *frame_2;
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout_2;
    QLabel *label_3;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer_3;
    QLabel *label_4;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        if (MainWindow->objectName().isEmpty())
            MainWindow->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MainWindow"));
        MainWindow->resize(878, 632);
        centralWidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
        centralWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("centralWidget"));
        verticalLayout_3 = new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget);
        verticalLayout_3->setSpacing(6);
        verticalLayout_3->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        verticalLayout_3->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("verticalLayout_3"));
        top_frame = new QFrame(centralWidget);
        top_frame->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("top_frame"));
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(top_frame->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        top_frame->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
        top_frame->setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);
        top_frame->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);
        gridLayout = new QGridLayout(top_frame);
        gridLayout->setSpacing(6);
        gridLayout->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        gridLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("gridLayout"));
        horizontalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(30, 20, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        gridLayout->addItem(horizontalSpacer, 0, 2, 1, 1);

        progressBar_2 = new QProgressBar(top_frame);
        progressBar_2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("progressBar_2"));
        progressBar_2->setValue(24);

        gridLayout->addWidget(progressBar_2, 2, 3, 1, 1);

        progressBar_4 = new QProgressBar(top_frame);
        progressBar_4->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("progressBar_4"));
        progressBar_4->setValue(24);

        gridLayout->addWidget(progressBar_4, 2, 5, 1, 1);

        verticalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(20, 10, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Fixed);

        gridLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer, 1, 1, 1, 1);

        horizontalSpacer_2 = new QSpacerItem(10, 20, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        gridLayout->addItem(horizontalSpacer_2, 0, 4, 1, 1);

        pushButton_1 = new QPushButton(top_frame);
        pushButton_1->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton_1"));

        gridLayout->addWidget(pushButton_1, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        progressBar_1 = new QProgressBar(top_frame);
        progressBar_1->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("progressBar_1"));
        progressBar_1->setValue(24);

        gridLayout->addWidget(progressBar_1, 0, 3, 1, 1);

        pushButton_2 = new QPushButton(top_frame);
        pushButton_2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton_2"));

        gridLayout->addWidget(pushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        pushButton_3 = new QPushButton(top_frame);
        pushButton_3->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton_3"));

        gridLayout->addWidget(pushButton_3, 2, 0, 1, 1);

        progressBar_3 = new QProgressBar(top_frame);
        progressBar_3->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("progressBar_3"));
        progressBar_3->setValue(24);

        gridLayout->addWidget(progressBar_3, 0, 5, 1, 1);

        pushButton_4 = new QPushButton(top_frame);
        pushButton_4->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton_4"));

        gridLayout->addWidget(pushButton_4, 2, 1, 1, 1);


        verticalLayout_3->addWidget(top_frame);

        bottom_frame = new QFrame(centralWidget);
        bottom_frame->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("bottom_frame"));
        bottom_frame->setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);
        bottom_frame->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);
        horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(bottom_frame);
        horizontalLayout->setSpacing(6);
        horizontalLayout->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        horizontalLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("horizontalLayout"));
        frame = new QFrame(bottom_frame);
        frame->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("frame"));
        frame->setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);
        frame->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);
        formLayout = new QFormLayout(frame);
        formLayout->setSpacing(6);
        formLayout->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        formLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("formLayout"));
        label_1 = new QLabel(frame);
        label_1->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("label_1"));

        formLayout->setWidget(0, QFormLayout::LabelRole, label_1);

        label_2 = new QLabel(frame);
        label_2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("label_2"));

        formLayout->setWidget(1, QFormLayout::LabelRole, label_2);

        verticalSpacer_2 = new QSpacerItem(20, 20, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        formLayout->setItem(2, QFormLayout::LabelRole, verticalSpacer_2);

        lineEdit = new QLineEdit(frame);
        lineEdit->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("lineEdit"));
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy1(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
        sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(lineEdit->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        lineEdit->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1);

        formLayout->setWidget(3, QFormLayout::SpanningRole, lineEdit);

        lineEdit_2 = new QLineEdit(frame);
        lineEdit_2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("lineEdit_2"));
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(lineEdit_2->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        lineEdit_2->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1);

        formLayout->setWidget(4, QFormLayout::LabelRole, lineEdit_2);


        horizontalLayout->addWidget(frame);

        frame_2 = new QFrame(bottom_frame);
        frame_2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("frame_2"));
        frame_2->setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);
        frame_2->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);
        horizontalLayout_2 = new QHBoxLayout(frame_2);
        horizontalLayout_2->setSpacing(6);
        horizontalLayout_2->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        horizontalLayout_2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("horizontalLayout_2"));
        label_3 = new QLabel(frame_2);
        label_3->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("label_3"));

        horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(label_3);

        horizontalSpacer_3 = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        horizontalLayout_2->addItem(horizontalSpacer_3);

        label_4 = new QLabel(frame_2);
        label_4->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("label_4"));

        horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(label_4);

        frame->raise();
        frame->raise();
        label_3->raise();
        label_4->raise();

        horizontalLayout->addWidget(frame_2);


        verticalLayout_3->addWidget(bottom_frame);

        MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

        retranslateUi(MainWindow);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        MainWindow->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", 0));
        pushButton_1->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "PushButton_1", 0));
        pushButton_2->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "PushButton_2", 0));
        pushButton_3->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "PushButton_3", 0));
        pushButton_4->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "PushButton_4", 0));
        label_1->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel_1", 0));
        label_2->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel_2", 0));
        label_3->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel_3", 0));
        label_4->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel_4", 0));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow: public Ui_MainWindow {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: The recommended practice is avoid huge monolithic GUIs, organize elements into smaller widgets and combine them, especially if they can be repeated such as your two columns each of 2 buttons and 2 progress bars. Also the question is too broad and primarily opinion based.

Comment: @ddriver I put effort not to make the question broad and certainly not opinion-based although I see what you mean and you do have a point. Nevertheless, I am looking for a small chunk of code demonstrating a few definitions and invocations specifically to demonstrate Qt nested layouts with multiple widgets for me to learn; no proper examples online as far as I can tell.

Comment: You nest any widget just like you nest a plain `QWidget`. Make a `TwoButtons : public QWidget` class and you have a widget that's two buttons, put 2 of whose in another widget, and you have a widget with 4 buttons. Just follow the general Qt programming guidelines - properties, signals and slots interfaces for your widgets to make them truly modular.

Comment: @If you could provide a full (no matter how small) code to support your description it would be great for me to study.

Comment: @nk-fford , organizing elements into smaller widgets and combining them into building blocks are mentioned by ddriver is recommended even when using the designer. You can have a form for a separate complicated widget and re-use that form in the designer in your main window or in a dialog as long as you wish.

Comment: So, are you looking for C++ code for your GUI? or are you asking for what components you should separate in the GUI you show?

Comment: @Mike I look for a good full example of code that imitates the nested layout and multiple widgets design in the GUI description. My aim is to see how we can programmatically design nested layouts and widgets using the header and the source files in C++ Qt.

Comment: the [Qt User Interface](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html) automatically generates C++ code for the XML generated by the Qt designer. you can have a look at that automatically generated code for the GUI you show in your screenshot, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36512581/2666212). You can add as many nested layouts as you want in the designer and see how does that translate in C++.

Comment: @Mike Wow, I had no idea that such a tool existed. Will try it now. If you care to provide an answer with such a code I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: @nk-fford , this *tool* is how Qt works, this is how the GUI you design in the designer is compiled into the result executable. It is just translated into C++. that's why you call `ui->setupUi(this)` in your window's constructor.

Comment: @Mike I studied the output of the `Qt User Interface`; very useful. However, the part of my question for which I seeking advice/code example to demonstrate how such code should be separated on both the `.h` and `.cpp` source files still stands; I pressume it is not good practice (objectively not based on opinions) to have all the GUI on the `.cpp` and not put the definitions on the `.h`. Could you care to provide an example snippet of such a separation?

Comment: @nk-fford. If the output of `uic` somehow doesn't satisfy your requirements, there are dozens of [example programs in the qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html) that may do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a transformation that you might wish to perform. I've included a shortened version of your code to demonstrate.

1. Start with `uic` output.

   ```
   class Ui_MainWindow
   {
   public:
       QWidget *centralWidget;
       QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout_3;
       QFrame *top_frame;
   };
   ```
2. Put all members of `Ui_Foo` into `Foo` itself, retaining their order.

   ```
   class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
   {
       QWidget *centralWidget;
       QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout_3;
       QFrame *top_frame;
   };
   ```
3. Change member types from pointers to values.

   ```
   class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
   {
       QWidget centralWidget;
       QVBoxLayout verticalLayout_3;
       QFrame top_frame;
       ...
   };
   ```
4. Initialize layouts in the class declaration by giving them the widgets they act on. This makes the structure of the user interface all obvious from the header itself:

   ```
   class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
   {
       QWidget centralWidget;
       QVBoxLayout verticalLayout_3{&centralWidget};
       QFrame top_frame;
       ...
   };
   ```
5. Add code from `setupUi` to the constructor's body, changing it appropriately to act on values, not pointers:

   ```
   MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent) : QWidget{parent}
   {
       setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MainWindow"));
       resize(878, 632);
       centralWidget.setObjectName(QStringLiteral("centralWidget"));
       verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(6);
       verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
       verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(QStringLiteral("verticalLayout_3"));
       top_frame.setObjectName(QStringLiteral("top_frame"));
       QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
       sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
       sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
       sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(top_frame->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
       top_frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
       top_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);
       top_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Do you know why if there is a `QSpacerItem` in the ui (e.g. `QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer;` then if I follow your guide and put it in `class MainWindow : public QWidget` from pointers to values I get the error `C2512: 'QSpacerItem': no appropriate default constructor available`. Any suggestions why and how to avoid?

Comment: If you use a compiler that supports uniform member initialization, the you should initialize the spacer (and all other members!) in its declaration: `QSpacerItem foo{....}`, where `....` are the arguments that its constructor demands. If you use an older compiler, you need to initialize it in the [member initializer list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8523361/1329652).