# Missing attributes and methods in QT ui pointer

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm building a user interface with qt creator. I've created a StartWindow class extending a QMainWindow. After the creation, I've added new methods and attributes. Automatically QT Creator generates this Kind of code for the header file:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
namespace Ui {
class StartWindow;
}

class StartWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit StartWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~StartWindow();
public:
int i;
private:
Ui::StartWindow *ui;
};
```

Now, when i try to give i the value 2, from the cpp file:

```
ui->i = 2;
```

I get this error:

> /home/carl/QT5Projects/DopProject/startwindow.cpp:13: error: 'class Ui::StartWindow' has no member named 'i'

but I can access to `i` through the scope resolution operator

```
StartWindow::i = 0;
```

or

```
this->i = 0;
```

Neither can I access `i` through

```
this->ui->i = 0;
```

Could someone explain that to me?

Comment: What makes you think that you should access `i` from `ui`? `i`and `ui` are both class member variables, you should be accessing `i` the same way you are accessing `ui`.

Comment: Because ui is a  StartWindow pointer type

Answer (score 3):

The `StartWindow` class has `i` and `ui` as two separate data members. `i` is not a member of `ui`, but of the `StartWindow` object itself. Hence the containment is like this:

```
StartWindow object
      |   |
      i   ui
```

and not like this:

```
StartWindow object
      |
      ui
      |
      i
```

That's why you cannot access `i` through `ui`, but you must access it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Both `i` and `ui` are class member variables, you should be accessing `i` the same way you are accessing `ui`.

> ui is a StartWindow pointer type.

`ui` is **not** of type `StartWindow*`, it is of `Ui::StartWidow*` type. This is a completely separate class, despite having the same name, it is declared in the `Ui` namespace at the beginning of your `startwindow.h` file:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
//class declaration
namespace Ui {
class StartWindow;
}
//...
```

This class is generated by the [Qt User Interface Compiler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html) from the `startwindow.ui` file that have been created by the designer. By default, the class is used at the beginning of your `StartWindow` class's constructor by calling its `setupUi()` member function:

```
StartWindow::StartWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    //an instance of Ui::StartWindow is created
    ui(new Ui::StartWindow)
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    //the instance is used to create the widgets and set up layouts
    //that you have defined in the designer
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //...
}
```

The `Ui::StartWindow` class is defined in the file `ui_startwindow.h` which should be included in the beginning of your `startwindow.cpp` class. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36512131/2666212) for information about the `ui_startwindow.h` file.